# Defining a subroutine in another subroutine

Tags: fortran, subroutine, fortran95, silverfrost-fortran

Is it possible in Fortran to define a subroutine within another subroutine? When I try something like

```
SUBROUTINE test1(...)
  ! do some stuff
  CALL test2(...)

  SUBROUTINE test2(...)
    ! do some stuff
  END SUBROUTINE test2
END SUBROUTINE test1.
```

my compiler (Silverfrost) gives me a recursion error.

Comment: If you want to have the word Fortran as a part of the title in some specific place, go ahead, but just `Fortran:` should not be used. Tags should not be just copied to the title.

Comment: @agentp If you are on larger retagging work, consider using `silverfrost-fortran` and not `silverfrost` similar to [tag:intel-fortran] and [tag:nag-fortran].

Comment: @VladimirF agreed. is there a way to edit the tag or do i make a new one and switch them?

Comment: @agentp You have to retag the questions with the new tag. The old one will be removed automatically if it does not have any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As HighPerformanceMark comments, it is possible to define an *internal procedure* in the contains section of another procedure

```
SUBROUTINE test1(...)
  ! do some stuff
  CALL test2(...)

CONTAINS

  SUBROUTINE test2(...)
    ! do some stuff
  END SUBROUTINE test2
END SUBROUTINE test1
```

The internal procedure `test2` gets access to all entities defined in the host procedure `test1` by *host association*. It also gets access to all entities that `test1` has access to. The rules are similar to the rules of internal procedures in the main program.

An internal procedure cannot host another internal procedure.

Procedure pointers to internal procedures are only valid during the execution of the host procedure and are only allowed in Fortran 2008 and later. This is an advanced feature.

This host association can sometimes be annoying, you must be vigilant to avoid bugs like:

```
SUBROUTINE test1(...)
  integer :: i

  do i  = 1, n
    CALL test2(...)
  end do

CONTAINS

  SUBROUTINE test2(...)
    do i = 1, n
      !i here is the same variable as i in test1!!
    end do
  END SUBROUTINE test2
END SUBROUTINE test1
```

There will be features in Fortran 2015 to change the host association behaviour.